# how keras.Model.fit works?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am making a custom keras Model. I want to customize the training loop so I implemented a custom train_step method. I want to understand the logic of the fit method. As of my understanding, train_step is used in the fit method and test_step in the evaluate method and predict_step in the predict method. How does the fit function handle the validation data set in the fit call? I tried asking gemini and the answer was **"it is not the train_step because there are no updates on the gradient but it is not the test_step because it's used only in the evaluate method. but it is handled using a similar way to the train_step."** I tried looking into the documentation and the source code but didn't get any useful information.

I want to know what is the function that handles the validation data set and if you can explain the whole logic of the fit method.

Comment: since you are working on AI you probably know that AI gives mostly wrong answers.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch#low-level_handling_of_metrics. Scroll a bit down or search "validation loop". First result on "tensorflow custom training loop" search... it's not that hard to find.